How can I constraint the combination of multiple fields in solr to be unqiue?
I have a solr schema with fields "title", "source", and "location" set as strings. How can I make sure that there are not two document with the exact same "title", "source", and "location".

Index them as a single field and define that field as unique or as the id field.

@MatsLindh Is it possible make multiple fields be unique? I tried that and I was getting errors.

No, not as far as I remember. A unique key in Solr is what you'll use to update documents - they're not really used to deny an update if necessary (you can use optimistic updates for that, by selecting for a document with the value in a field, and then issue an update afterwards if the document isn't present).
